# How to use VNC through eclipse (on ubuntu)

Tags: vnc

what shell I do in order to remote to my friend's pc, using VNC through Eclipse?

important: the way I'm looking for should be one that doesn't use the ubunto terminal.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to make sure that your question provides sufficient information to readers so you can be helped

Comment: Ok 
i've found a way for doing this, by writing a code in an Eclipse project  which automatically opens the cmd prompt and connect my pc via VNC  by using a static IP address that represent my friend's pc. 
I'm now looking for commands that will allow me to:(automaticly from a written code)  
1. open the cmd prompt  
2. get a static IP address
3. connect to vnc. (including getting pswd and connecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the way I wanted the auto remoted connection to be was not good because it made an indirectly connection (by automatically calling the cmd prompt and opening VNC through it)
It works but there is a better way for doing this:
The right thing to do is to write a code that uses the RFB protocol. By implementing the three following steps(in my case- in a eclipse project)-you can get an automated VNC remoting connection: hand-shake,client & server init and then the normal protocol interaction.